# Nx custom builder asp.net core nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net, .net-core

I started to use Nx monorepos to manage my reactjs projects but like to use an asp.net core backend.
What I would like to do is create a custom builder to run my dotnet watch run command in a custom executor\builder and execute not the webpack server but a dotnet server. So I try to execute the dotnet cli from nodejs.
I made an app.js to test and try to run:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const fs = require("fs");

const out = fs.openSync("./out.log", "a");
const err = fs.openSync("./out.log", "a");

const subprocess = spawn("dotnet", ["run", "--project", "./apps/asp-web"], {
  detached: true,
  stdio: ["pipe", out, err],
});
subprocess.unref();
```

This seems to work but I do not seem to be able to run it inside the active node console so `detached:false` and also I can not seem to find a way to run the command `dotnet watch run --project ./apps/asp-web`
is there a better solution for doing this?

Comment: Hey! Did you figure something out?

Comment: Did you consider [custom commands](https://nx.dev/latest/angular/guides/running-custom-commands)?